# How to remove roller shade?

Tags: windows, blinds

The side without the bead chain on my roller shade looks like this:
[image]

How do I remove it? Google says to stick a flathead screwdriver into the tab between the bracket and to pull down on the bar, but it doesn't budge and I don't want to break anything;
[image]

Here is the picture of the other side with the bead string - the reason I want to take it down is so that I can reattach the bead string

[image]

Comment: it looks like the right side of the mounting bracket possibly slides towards you (away from the wall) .... it is also possible that you have to unclip the other end of the shade first

Comment: Let's see the bracket on the other side.

Comment: other side added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab needs to be pulled down (it may need to be moved sideways as in the second photo before it can be pulled out and the bar will slide down the notch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for great photos. Try putting the flat blade of the screwdriver between the metal of the end of the shade and the plastic bracket and gently pry the bracket away from the shade.